# Exchange: Is it possible to search for a custom Extended Property across all mailboxes?

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2007, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, ews-managed-api

My team and I are in the process of integrating our custom CRM (built entirely on the MS stack) with Exchange.  A key part of that integration is binding Exchange items (namely meetings and tasks) to customer records.  Basically, when a salesperson schedules a meeting with a certain customer, the customer's GUID is attached to that meeting as a custom [extended property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633691%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx).  Simple enough, right?

When we are dealing with a single mailbox, [searching for a custom extended property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633697%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx) is easy.  But what about multiple mailboxes e.g., searching *all* salesperson calendars for meetings that have a certain customer's GUID attached as a custom extended property?

**Is it possible to search across all (or several) mailboxes for a given custom extended property?**  Is binding our data using custom extended properties even the correct approach?

---

**Environment**: We're using the [EWS Managed API](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2009/04/21/451126.aspx) to talk to an Exchange 2010 server.  Exchange 2007 EWS with auto-gen proxies function in the same general manner, however, so suggestions relating to 2007 should be applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to do a search across multiple mailboxes at once.  You'll need to connect into each mailbox individually and do the search that way.